# Using async/await to find the value of a cors request?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, async-await

I'm attempting to execute a `CORS` request, then use *async/await* to get value out of it (I'm using jquery btw).

The functions `createCORSRequest` and executeCORSRequest both work fine I believe, so the implementation doesn't really matter. The function `getDailyGames` uses await to receive a promise created from `executeCORSRequest`, and then returns that promise.

My trouble is with actually using the promise in the `$(document)`.ready function (this is basically the main function in jquery).

In the commented out line, the '.then' the method is used on the result of `getDailyGames` to print out the result of the function (this works fine).

However, I want to store the value of this promise in the 'result' variable and do stuff to it, but I can't get it out of the promise.

How would I correctly return this promise so that I can store the resolved value in a variable and do stuff with it?

Or another way to ask this: why does the 'result' variable in `getDailyGames` get a promise? Shouldn't use await with a promise give you the resolved value directly?

```
$(document).ready(function() {    
  //getDailyGames(20190313).then(result => console.log(result));
  let result = getDailyGames(20190313);
  //DO STUFF WITH RESULT    
});

async function getDailyGames(date){    
  const url = 'https://api.jjjacobson.com/dailygames?season=2018-2019- 
  regular&date=' + date;
  let result = await executeCORSRequest(url);
  return result;    
}

function executeCORSRequest(url){
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    const xhr = createCORSRequest('GET', url);
      if (!xhr) {
        throw new Error('CORS not supported');
      }
      xhr.onload = function() {
        resolve(xhr.responseText);
      };  

      xhr.onerror = function() {
        console.log('There was an error!');
        reject('ERROR');
      };    
      xhr.send();
    });
}

function createCORSRequest(method, url) {
  let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  if ("withCredentials" in xhr) {    
    // Check if the XMLHttpRequest object has a "withCredentials" property.
    // "withCredentials" only exists on XMLHTTPRequest2 objects.
    xhr.open(method, url, true);    
  } 
  else if (typeof XDomainRequest != "undefined") {    
    // Otherwise, check if XDomainRequest.
    // XDomainRequest only exists in IE, and is IE's way of making CORS requests.
    xhr = new XDomainRequest();
    xhr.open(method, url);    
  } 
  else {    
    // Otherwise, CORS is not supported by the browser.
    xhr = null;    
  }
  return xhr;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should change your document.ready function to:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  let result;
  getDailyGames(20190313).then(res => {
    result = res;
    //DO STUFF WITH RESULT

  });
});
```

`Await` works only when the function itself is async. You could also do this

```
$(document).ready(async function() {

  let result = await getDailyGames(20190313);
  //DO STUFF WITH RESULT

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Async/await is only syntactical sugar aiming at eliminating the callback hell. It should be remembered well that somewhere down the asynchronous chain, you will have to deal with a promise. This is the reason why you can use `await` only inside `async` function and, sadly, the root of the script is not an `async` function.

In your case, if you want to serialize the call to `getDailyGames`, make the document.ready an async function as indicated by @varun.